# How to fix color reflection on object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I'm trying to put an object on a backdrop image. After copying it out of the original image and placing it upon the backdrop I realized it had a blue reflection from the object it stood next to it.

What is the best way to re-adjust the color back to its original beige tone?

The image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost the same answer as user287001 - but with a couple of differences.

Add a Hue/Saturation adjustment layer instead, and check the "colorize" option, then change the colour slightly so it looks beige. But then clip the adjustment layer to just the chair layer, so that it doesn't colourize the underlying layers.

Done this way, the edit will be non destructive.

For example:
[image]

Comment: @beetroot This is the pro way. Learn this!

Answer (score 1):

You can desaturate or hue-shift or both a color range with Image > Adjustments > Hue & Saturation:

[image]

The hue shift is only +2 and the saturation was taken down to -88%. Search carefully with the bottom color sliders the range which needs adjustments.

NOTE: It's essential to learn properly the meaning of all controls to get usable results.

Without a background a single color object can be recolorized:

[image]

ADDENDUM: Just in case you were in hurry and happened to make the red markings to the chair instead of the photo, you should treat them at first:

[image]

Now the image is more ready for the removal of blue.